# Discord.JS Prevent a person from writing a message

Tags: discord.js

The messages sent by the person whose ID I enter with the code below are automatically deleted.

```
    client.on('message', msg => {
if (msg.author.id === 'id') {
  msg.delete();
}
});
```

However, I have to update my identity from the console every time.

I want to do this with a command. Example "!sh ID" or "!sh @Example"

Could you help?

Comment: You're going to have to use a database to store those IDs then check if the author ID matches any IDs stored

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do it, with an array or with a database

The first one, an array is much more simple, when someone runs the command you append the ID to an array. However the array will reset each time the bot stops

```js
const userid = const taggedUser = message.mentions.users.first().id || args[0]
delete.push(userid)
```

then your delete message code will become

```js
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (delete.includes(msg.author.id)) {
    msg.delete();
  }
});
```

The database is more advanced, when someone runs the command it adds their id to a table

Then you would get all the IDs from the database, add them to an array and use the same code as before to delete the messages.

Comment: Thanks, but I encountered syntax errors.

When I add it as you specified i got an error when defining TaggedUser

I revised it this way and got rid of the error:  `const userid = taggedUser = message.mentions.users.first().id || args[0]`

But this time too `delete.push(userid)` in line I got the error SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'